# Uninstalled fb module, but page still pings fb connect for every pageload

Tags: social-network

I uninstalled the fb module and all its submodules from my site and deleted /sites/all/modules/fb folder completely. But for every pageload, the site still calls for these files:

1. http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
   and a few others.

I want them removed as these slow down my pages completely. I have nothing other than a facebook like button on my homepage, and this was added with sexybookmarks. Any help?

Comment: @Bala I have removed my comments from this discussion as it is not going to help future visitors. I suggest that you do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was added by the facebook share button added by sexybookmarks, Disabling that removed the files as well.

Comment: You should select this as the correct answer.